# What are popular Chinese songs for toddlers?

Tags: lyrics

I am trying to teach my daughter Chinese.
Since she loves to sing songs in English, I believe that teaching her to sing Chinese songs will help her to learn more Chinese.
Unfortunately, because I did not grow up singing Chinese songs, I don't know what songs parents sing to their toddlers in China/Taiwan.

**Question:** What are popular Chinese songs for toddlers?

Comment: Welcome to Chinese Language, Your question seems to be off-topic, Have a look at [help/on-topic] for more information. also remember 'Open-ended, chatty questions are explicitly discouraged on the Stack Exchange network'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a lot of:

1）[小兔子乖乖](http://app.baidu.com/app/enter?appid=108606)

2）[数鸭子](http://app.baidu.com/app/enter?appid=143561)

3）[马兰花](http://app.baidu.com/app/enter?appid=249688)

4）[找朋友](http://app.baidu.com/app/enter?appid=228216)

For more, please refer to：[儿童歌曲列表](http://app.baidu.com/app/enter?appid=139616)